# LGPL/MPL and static libraries

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, static-libraries, lgpl

I need to compile LGPL licensed code into a proprietary static iOS library. Since the code is used in static library I can't link against a precompiled version of the LGPL licensed library.

How do I go about this, and what do I have to release if I compile it into my lib? I obviously can't release the (whole) proprietary source.

The specific library I am talking about is libical which is licensed under LGPL 2.1 or MPL 1.0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You may be able to get help on [Programmers Stack Exchange, but **read their faq carefully** before proceeding.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefacing this with the usual IANAL:

Depends on the version of the LGPL it's using. If version 2, you do not need to supply your source code until asked for it. That's the way the license is written. However, when it's asked for, you will need to provide it via some easily accessible medium.

If it's LGPLv3, my suggestion is to find another library. The GPLv3 family of licenses are not compatible with AppStore distribution at all.

Comment: updated my question. lgpl 2.1 or mpl 1.0.

Comment: If i need to release the source, this only includes the files that interface with the LGPL lib is that right?

Comment: That's for a lawyer to determine definitively I'm afraid. Myself, I always like isolating LGPL'd code as much as possible, but I never use it in projects I'm not ready to open the source to if requested.

Answer (score 1):

The LGPL license says you need to provide three bits:

1. The LGPL source-code as used in your product.
2. The object-files of your proprietary code
3. A tool to build the source-code and link it with the object-files, resulting in the very same product you submitted to Appstore.

It is tedious and complicated, but very doable.